# How to append using to_csv such that blank rows can be manipulated

Tags: python, dataframe, append

I have a DataFrame that I need to append to an existing csv file. I am able to append it, but how can I leave a row after the existing text in the csv?

Also, how can I not have a space between the column header and the column entry?

The current code I have is:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

files_too_large = []

df_large = pd.DataFrame()

files_too_large = ['Large_File.dxl']

if len(files_too_large) > 0:
    write_large_files = {'Files too large to process': files_too_large}
    df_large = pd.DataFrame(write_large_files, columns = ['Files too large to process'])
    with open('C:\\Users\\rmore\\Desktop\\try\\C.csv','a') as f:
        df_large.to_csv(f, index = False)
```

Basically when I append to existing csv, I want an empty row above the appended column header - 'Files too large to process'
And I don't want an empty row between the appended column header and the appended filename - 'Large_File.dxl'

Thank you

R

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my question using writerows instead.
I did not use the pandas dataframe approach.

For getting a blank row above, I wrote a blank row at the end of the previous text.

All good.